# Separate Date Month and year form a date field in Adobe acrobat DC using java script

Tags: javascript, date, pdf

Please help me with a java script for  adobe acrobat dc
A user input field is available with a date given by the user.

The script should read this field and give the date, month and year in three seperate output fields
I have a sample script here below, but when tried says 'syntax error'

```
var beginDate = this.getField("DateInput").valueAsString;
if (beginDate=="") event.value = " ";
esle {
var oDateValue = util.scand("mm dd, yyyy",beginDate);
event.value = util.printd("yyyy", oDateValue);}
```

Comment: tell us what you have tried and guve more information, we arent here to do your homework.

Comment: this is what i tried sir 
    var beginDate = this.getField("DateInput").valueAsString;
    if (beginDate=="") event.value = " ";
    esle {
    var oDateValue = util.scand("mm dd, yyyy",beginDate);
    event.value = util.printd("yyyy", oDateValue);}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

You have an error in your code. you misstyped `esle`, replace it with `else`.

Comment: If it's just a typo, vote to close.

Comment: @RobG well it could be a new developer who doesnt know its a typo and is just learning, so might as well help right? we all started somewhere

Comment: It's worth pointing out the correction as a comment, not an answer. The range of possible typos that produce syntax errors is practically infinite, so useless to have answers for every one that arrises. That's why "typo" is one of the stock reasons to close a question.

Comment: @RobG Alright, you have a fair reason for that. thanks for telling me :)